# Preinstall a promotional iPad app on a free iPad when someone buys a product doable?

Tags: iphone, ipad

We went to give out a free iPad when someone buys our product. And on that iPad we want to preinstall an in-house made promotional App, which will just be HTML enclosed in an app.

Is this doable and legal?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to activate the iPad or set it up for them in order to reliably get the app on there. I don't know that you have that option though. A better choice may be to give them a promo code they can use in the app store to download the app.